# Why is this JavaScript code not working?

Tags: javascript

Why is this code working? I want to take the input variable and getting the emails out of it. It's not working though. Can someone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">


var email = /[a-z0-9\.&%]+@(?:[a-z1-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,4}/i;
var input = "hi4d@gmail.com@gmail.com text here shaagd4@@fdfdg.ct hefds@4564dh-dsdgd.ly";
var testout = true;
var output;
while(testout === true)
{
var execoutput = email.exec(input);
testout = email.test(input);
if(!output) {output = '';}
if(testout === true)
{
output += "<p>An email found was: " + execoutput[0] + ".</p>";
input = input.substring(execoutput[0].length);
}
}
document.write(output);
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have been here long enough to know that "It's not working" is not enough of a problem description. What _is_ happening? Errors? Incorrect results (which are...)? Something else?

Comment: Indenting scopes help you with reading your code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fNmns/ <-- Straight copy of your code. It works.

Comment: @DarkLightA I think you should work on coming up with better questions. Remember that questions are supposed to be useful to other people in the future who may have problems similar to yours. A question title like the one you've used here (and many other times) is useless for future searches because it indicates nothing at all about the nature of your problem.

Comment: There's no good reason for `while (testout===true)` or `if (testout===true)`; just use `while (testout)` and `if (testout)`. _(This will not solve your problem, but will improve your code.)_

Comment: Also, @DarkLightA, **stop using `document.write()` for your testing**.  It's a bad habit and it's always going to confuse things.

Comment: Next time, try including a description of the expected result and the result you are obtaining. "It's not working" is definitively not detailed enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: ([on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XdGKe/))

```
var email = /[a-z0-9\.&%]+@(?:[a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,4}/i;
var input = "hi4d@gmail.com@gmail.com text here shaagd4@@fdfdg.ct hefds@4564dh-dsdgd.ly";
var output = '';

for (;;) {
    var execoutput = email.exec(input);

    if (!execoutput) {
        break;
    }

    output += "<p>An email found was: " + execoutput[0] + ".</p>";
    input = input.substring(execoutput.index + execoutput[0].length);
}

document.write(output);
```

Note a few problems I've corrected:

- The regex did not match the 0 character in the domain part.  None of your input strings contained this character in the domain part, but it was a bug nonetheless.
- You can't just pull off the first N characters of the input string when N is the length of the matched string, because it may not have matched at position 0.  You have to add the index of the match too, or you might match the same address multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the code works.

It should however be duly noted I just slapped your code straight into my current project (Yay for messing up stuff!) and it works just fine there too.

HOWEVER it does not LOOK right, nor provide the correct output I suspect you want.